# How to center one child vertically in multi child parent view in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a view A (View - Image) which is a parent to B (Text) and C (Text). I want B Text to always be vertically and horizontally centered in A. The problem with using `alignItems: 'center'`, `justifyContent: 'center'` on the container A is that it considers the combined height of B *and* C, then centers them vertically based on their combined height. I simply want B centered inside A, and I want C to be aligned on the bottom.

- B must always be vertically aligned center, regardless of it's height or the length of text that B contains.
- C must always be aligned to the bottom of container A.

Here is a visual of what I'm trying to get:

[image]

And some code as an example:

```
<View style={styles.viewA}>
    <Text style={styles.textB}>
      I should be vertically centered in A, regardles of my size or the size / place of C.
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.TextC}>
      I should be on the bottom of A
    </Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewA: {
    height: 360,
    width: 360,
    alignItems: 'center', // doesn't work
    justifyContent: 'center', // doesn't work
    ???: ???
  },
  viewB: {
    ???
  },
  viewC: {
    ???
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [React Native's Flexbox](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#content) to align the items. Here's how:

```
<View style={styles.viewA}>
  <View style={styles.textB}>
     <Text>
    I should be vertically centered in A, regardles of my size or the size / place of C.</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.TextC}>
    <Text>
      I should be on the bottom of A
    </Text>
 </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 viewA: {
  height: 360,
  width: 360,
  alignItems: 'center', // doesn't work
  justifyContent: 'center', // doesn't work
  flex: 1
 },
 viewB: {
  flex: .8
 },
 viewC: {
  flex: .2
 }
});
```